# My old webhost has gone out of business. How can I recover the text of my website?

Tags: cache

I found my website in the Wayback Machine a few months ago.

My old webhost stopped paying for their servers back in August without any notice. I was going to do a backup the day it happened.

**Is there a way just to find the text of my website?** I have the old IP, images, but nothing else. None of the big search engines have caches anymore, and I already looked in the cache of three of my Macs with nothing to be found.

I tried looking for my website in the Wayback Machine again today, but I got a strange error:  it tells me it can't find robots.txt.

Comment: Can you share the URL of your website? Depending on how popular your site was, you may check if some of the tricks mentioned here work for you - http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/12/international-backup-awareness-day.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you've exhausted the options.  If the Wayback Machine doesn't have it and Google doesn't have it and there is no local copy of it, it is gone.

The ISP might have copies of it in their backups and it may be worth contacting them. You can also [attempt to contact](http://archive.org/about/contact.php) the folks who run the archive to see if they can help with the robots.txt issue.  There is also a [mirror of the archive](http://www.bibalex.org/isis/frontend/archive/archive_web.aspx) and perhaps you will have better luck there.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is always 100% hindsight, but has to be repeated incessantly in the hopes people eventually pay attention.

If you value it, the No. 1 priority in website management? Learn how to back it up.

Magnetic blips on discs are transient and easily made to evaporate into the great bit bucket in the sky.